# Reporting status back to TeamCity when a test is ran locally

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, autoit

We have a testing framework made in AutoIt for our Windows apps (older legacy apps that we will continue supporting). These have never been run on a schedule or part of CI (always been run manually). I tried to get some kind of auto run (or even just status reporting) out of the tests, with minimal luck.

I have a VM where the tests can run. I experimented with my own web app, which works okay locally for running and status reporting. But when set up on the server, AutoIt reports it cannot open the application. Same thing happens if I try to run the tests from a .bat file.

My current solution is to have AutoIt call my web app to report status (working okay locally, untested on the server), or to see if I can get AutoIt to report results back to TeamCity. I have the agent installed but when I run the build from TeamCity, AutoIt reports it can't launch the application. I tried this while logged into the VM, logged out, with RDS open; no luck.

Is it possible to run the tests manually from the VM and send results back to TeamCity? When I run them from TeamCity it reads the AutoIt output (which is in the expected format), but I need to let TeamCity know to update the results (so we can use TeamCity rather than my web app to show the results).

I may need to find a way to let TeamCity know a build has been started, which might then let it know to keep an eye on the process' output, but I'm not positive. Any ideas?

Comment: TeamCity will have difficulties understanding such an "externally-managed" build. Could you please give more details on problems with starting AutoIt from usual TC build? What happens, what are the error messages etc.

How is build agent configured? is it started as a sevice or from script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this so it could be done more traditionally.

If anyone is confused by what "running the agent from the console" meant, it just means installing the agent without selecting the "as a service" checkbox, and then manually starting the agent by cd'ing to the `BuildAgent/bin` directory and running the command `agent start`. I also created a batch file that will do this automatically (but you must run it as admin).

Further, I found AutoIt couldn't do anything if the test doesn't run from the right directory, so I had to devise a solution to this.

The only issue now is that I have to have an old laptop always connected to the virtual machine the tests and app run on (since the AutoIt tests won't work without the VM desktop being interactive).